# Calculating the edge pixels within a fishnet

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro

I have a raster with three land cover classes.

For a fishnet grid cell, I want to calculate how many pixels (in %) are "edge pixels" (pixels from different land classes that touch). E.g., if the fishnet grid only contains 1 land cover class, the edge pixels % is 0%. If there two or more classes and many edge/boundary pixels, then the amount of edge pixels is above 0%.

How can I do this in ArcGIS Pro?

When I search online for a tool, it returns Edge detection for deep learning which is overkill.

Comment: Are you using the Spatial Analyst extension?  What have you tried besides a web search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach, use the tool [Focal Stats](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/focal-statistics.htm) and set the statistics type to VARIETY, this counts the number of pixel classes in the 3x3 neighbourhood.

So the input land cover raster could be something like this:

[image: Sample]

The result is this, anything greater than 1 must be a pixel adjacent to one or more other classes.

[image: result]

This approach not only identifies edge pixels but the value gives an indication to how many land class there are that are adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your understanding of edge pixel.
Picture below shows output of focal statistics (2 by 2 cells, Range) and vector boundary line. Note that cells where FS raster equal 0 are transparent:

[image]

You might try statistics of 3 by 3:

[image]

More appealing to me is this:

- derive internal boundary lines (raster to polygon polygon to line, delete features with LEFT_FID=-1)
- buffer them by 0.5*cell_width
- divide buffer area by cell size

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could write a python script (e.g. using rasterio) that makes a new raster that classifies your land cover pixels as "edge" or not, and then it would only be a matter of counting "edge" pixels within a fishnet cell.

```
import rasterio
import numpy

landcover_dataset = rasterio.open(yourInputFilePath)
landcover_band = dataset.read(1)

def IsEdge(band,r,c):
    #Make a function that looks at pixels adjacent to the pixel at (r, c) in band and returns True if it's an edge pixel, else False

edge_band = numpy.empty((#same size as input))
for r, row in enumerate(landcover_band):
    for c, column in enumerate(landcover_band):
        if IsEdge(landcover_band, r, c):
            edge_band[r][c] = 0
        else:
            edge_band[r][c] = 0

with rasterio.open(yourOutputFilepath, #same profile as input) as new_dataset:
    new_dataset.write(new_band)
```